# How to test if two phone are in close procimity(lets say 4-5 meters) to each other

Tags: java, android

One of the Feature in my app is to connect people physically and dynamical to each other when they come close to each others. like at events and stuff.

I have been doing research on how to connect two people
And i have Found things such as NFC and ISP a but I am new to android development(And coding in general) So I would like to know if it is possible to connect two phones and how so?

Much thanks

Answer (score 0):

Search about Kryonet Lib (java lib .jar ) , there is a feature "LAN server discovery" 
it works for android  https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryonet